# Text invisible in RStudio shell on server

Tags: r, shell, server, rstudio

When I access the RStudio (hosted on a server) shell (Tools > Shell...), I gain admin access by using `sudo R`, then typing my password, which I know is invisible for security reasons. However, every subsequent line of code I type is *also* invisible.

For example, say I want to download a package to make it available on the server. I use:

```
install.packages("spls", lib="/usr/lib/R/library")
```

The above text does not show up, but when I press Enter, it does execute and I'm asked for a mirror to use. The package then is correctly installed. Thus, the only problem is not being able to see the text. This happens for anything I type in the shell.

I'm not the host of the server, but I do know it uses Ubuntu, I believe the RStudio version is 0.99.473 and the R version is definitely 3.2.1. I'm running on a Mac with Yosemite and Safari. If more specific information would be helpful, I can contact the host.

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue and how to fix it?